# Inserting/Updating numeric string in Sqlite with Ruby (Newbie query)

Tags: ruby, sqlite, insert

I have a simple Sqlite table with 2 columns for a telephone number and a counter. I want to update the table on the basis of .csv files that also contain telephone numbers and counters. If the number exists in the database it should be updated by the sum of the existing counter + the counter in the file. If it doesn't exist a new record should be inserted with the value from the file.
My one remaining problem is that the telephone numbers have a zero in the first position.
When I populate the db the zero is retained, (I can manually select and find an existing number like 09999) when I fetch the values from the file the zero is retained but when I try to insert/update something happens in my Ruby code that inserts a new record without the leading zero, so 0999 becomes 999 in the db. Numbers without leading zeros are handled correctly.
My code looks like this:

```
rowArray=thisFile[k].split(';')
number = rowArray[0]
couplings = rowArray[1]


updString="INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Caller (Telno,count) VALUES (#{number},COALESCE((SELECT count + #{couplings} FROM Caller WHERE Telno=#{number}),#    {couplings}))"

db.execute(updString)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? The easiest solution would be to drop the leading zero but I would prefer to do it right. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use *placeholders* in your `prepare` call and pass the actual values in a call to `execute`. Like this

```
insert = db.prepare(<<__SQL__)
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Caller (Telno, count)
VALUES (:number, COALESCE((SELECT count + :couplings FROM Caller WHERE Telno = :number), :couplings))
__SQL__

insert.execute(number: number, couplings: couplings)
```

(Note that `:number` and `:couplings` in the SQL statement are *named placeholders*. They can be anything, but I have chosen them to match the corresponding names of the variables that are to be bound.)

The problem is that, using simple interpolation, you end up with a string like

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Caller (Telno, count) VALUES (0999, ...
```

and the `0999` appears to be a number rather than a string. If you pass strings to `execute` then the variables will be bound with the correct type.

Comment: Thanks Borodin, that fixed it and now I understand the mechanism.